# how to add TextInputs on every optionCount() click?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to add textInput component whenever the user clicks the icon. for this, I incremented answers.length but this is not working for me. So, please suggest any solution to this.

```
class CreateSurvey extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   var answers = [{answer: ''}];
   this.state = {
   answers,
   answerLength: answers.length
 };
}
optionCount() {
 this.setState({answerLength: answerLength + 1});
 this.state.answers.length = answerLength;
}
render(){
 return( 
  <View>
   <View>
    {
     this.state.answers.map((answer, index) =>
      <TextInput key={index} placeholder='Add answer variant'
        value={answer.answer}/>
       )
     }
   </View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.optionCount.bind(this)}>
    <EIcon name={'circle-with-plus'} />
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
   )
  }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you should increment the size of your array. It is technically valid, but your `map()` will only work for each *item* in the array, regardless of the specified size.

Have a look:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    let arr = new Array(4);
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    return (
      <ul>
        {arr.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

As you can see, even though we have an array that is `4` in length, it only has 2 values. Our `map()` only iterates twice, not 4 times.

---

To fix your issue, add another object to your `answers` array. Like so:

```js
optionCount() {
  let newAnswers = this.state.answers.slice();  //copy our answers array
  newAnswers.push({answer: ''}); //add a new answer object to our copy
  this.setState({answers: newAnswers}); //replace the old array with the new one
}
```